# How to avoid deleting emails from Dovecot

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap, pop3, dovecot

We have a Dovecot server configured for internal usage purpose and Thunderbird as a email client with `IMAP` protocol. I have never used either of the software, so my questions are a bit naive.

Due to some reasons we downloaded all emails to local Thunderbird uisng `POP3` few days back, now we are using `IMAP` and `POP3`(as backup purpose). Today first all messages are downloaded using `POP3` but in `IMAP`, messages after 20th JAN are only getting. I thought it is due to option having checked `Leave messages on Server` in POP3 settings. I'm confused that whether message before 20th JAN are remains on server or deleted, how to know this ?

[image]

Is the `POP3` server settings.

Comment: Wait a moment...is your setup like? Are you now using IMAP or POP3? They're pretty much exclusive to a certain extend.

Comment: I use both, POP3 as a backup because we have not taken any precautions  for unexpected disasters.

Answer (score 0):

Your messages before Jan 20 got deleted because you checked the option "Leave messages on server **for at most 14 days**". If you want to keep them all on the server, you need to uncheck that last part.